# Trying to get 2 sums within one table with addition of a join

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I've got a `submissions` table and in it are submissions that have the `type` either `tip` or `request`.

I'm trying to grab all the submissions of a particular user (to display as an aggregation of all their activity on their dashboard).

E.g.
`You have submitted: 5 requests and 1 tip`.

My submissions create table looks like this:

```
       Table: submissions
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `submissions` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('tip','request') NOT NULL,
  `thumbnail` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `removed` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `keywords` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ip` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `search` (`title`,`description`,`keywords`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I came up with one query that works and gives me the amount of the users' submissions, but because each submission (row that comes back) saves the type as either `tip` or `request`. So I'm trying to figure out how to aggregate that info now.

My query which returns the user with all `tip`s. I'm trying to do one for `request`s as well.

```
SELECT users.*, count(submissions.id) 
AS "tipsCount" 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN submissions on users.id = submissions.user_id 
WHERE username = 'blahbster' 
AND submissions.type = 'tip' 
ORDER BY submissions.created DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Perhaps I could use a sum here? My attempt:

```
SELECT users.*, 
SUM(case when type = 'tip' then 1 else 0 end) as "tipsCount"
SUM(case when type = 'request' then 1 else 0 end) as "requestsCount"
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN submissions on users.id = submissions.user_id 
WHERE username = 'blahbster' 
ORDER BY submissions.created DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.username, b.type,
SUM(case when b.type = 'tip' then 1 else 0 end) as "tipsCount",
SUM(case when b.type = 'request' then 1 else 0 end) as "requestsCount"
FROM users as a
LEFT JOIN submissions as b
ON a.id = b.user_id 
GROUP BY a.username, b.type;
```

The second query you had was close... but it wasn't aggregating a particular user's totals tips and total requests. The sum didn't compute across anything, ie, there was no GROUP BY.  The query above should help. You can obviously add the WHERE filter back in if you need it.